# How to disable routes for the DNS servers in Ubuntu 22.04？

Tags: networking, server, dns, dhcp

On Ubuntu 22.04，the route table can be gotten:

```
root@jammy-test-shengxpa:~# ip route
default via 62.109.210.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp src 62.109.211.31 metric 100 
10.240.240.1 via 62.109.210.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp src 62.109.211.31 metric 100 
10.240.241.1 via 62.109.210.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp src 62.109.211.31 metric 100 
62.109.210.0/23 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 62.109.211.31 metric 100 
62.109.210.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp scope link src 62.109.211.31 metric 100 
62.109.211.12 dev eth0 proto dhcp scope link src 62.109.211.31 metric 100 
169.254.169.254 via 62.109.211.12 dev eth0 proto dhcp src 62.109.211.31 metric 100 
192.168.255.0/24 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.255.1 linkdown
```

It shows I have 2 routes for the DNS Servers 10.240.240.1 & 10.240.241.1. I want to disable the two routes. I tried the "drop-in" configuration below:

```
for i in /run/systemd/network/10-netplan-*.network; do 
  drop_in="/etc/systemd/network/$(basename ${i}).d"
  mkdir -p "${drop_in}"
  cat <<EOF > "${drop_in}/override.conf"
[DHCPv4]
RoutesToDNS=false
EOF
done
```

But it doesn’t work. After run the command and reboot, the two routes still exist. How can I disable the two routes?

Comment: How are you configuring networking?  It is netplan?  If there are files in `/etc/netplan` or `/run/systemd/network` you should share the content.  The interface being named `eth0` suggests a specialized network setup may be in use.